# Gremlin python aggregate data

Tags: python, aggregate, gremlin

I want to exctract aggregate data like:

```
{category: 
     item: total_items
}
```

but I can't aggregate with multiple properties.

I write this query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('invoice').\
where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('year').has('value', between(2020, 2021))).\
where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('month').has('value', between(10, 12))).\
out('has_item').has('category', 'Technology').\
groupCount().by('name').\
order(Scope.local).by(Column.values, Order.desc).\
toList()
```

With this query I can exctract:

```
{item: total_items}
```

But how I can add category in this result? After groupCount I have no more that information.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to provide a few `addV` and `addE` steps that create a small sample graph and the expected results you need from that graph? I suspect all you need to do is nest two `group` steps but a little sample data would help offer a query that does what you need. Here is an example of a way to quickly create a sample graph: http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#btree

Answer (score 0):

You can nest as many `group` steps as you want. This should work just fine:

```
g.V().hasLabel('invoice').
  where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('year').has('value', between(2020, 2021))).
  where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('month').has('value', between(10, 12))).
  out('has_item').
  group().
    by('category').
    by(__.groupCount().by('name').
          order(Scope.local).
            by(Column.values, Order.desc))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I wanted... If I want aggregate also for year, I have to add a project function before the out?

Comment: Do you want it like `[year: [category: [name: count]]]` or `[category: [year: [name: count]]]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting suggestion Daniel.
I was looking at something similar but I got stuck, probably similar problem as Dav04..
For example, by using a similar query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('invoice').\
where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('year').has('value', between(2020, 2021))).\
where(__.out('created_in').hasLabel('month').has('value', between(10, 12))).as_('v').\
out('has_item').\
group().\
by(__.select('v').out('created_in').hasLabel('year').values('value')).\
by('category').\
by(__.groupCount().by('name').order(Scope.local).by(Column.values, Order.desc).range(Scope.local, 0,6)).\
toList()
```

I am struggling to understand how to extract for example a result like:

```
[
{
  2018: 
       {'service': [{'SaaS': 8}, {'DBaaS': 20}, {'IAM': 794}],
        'product': [{'Java Course': 8}, {'DB Course': 20}],
  2019: 
       {'service': [{'SaaS': 10}, {'DBaaS': XYZ}, {'IAM': XYZ}],
        'product': [{'Java Course': XYZ}, {'DB Course': XYZ}]  
}

]
```

Comment: Hi - it would be better if you could ask your question using a new post rather than asking a question in an answer otherwise things get a bit confusing. Also if you can provide a bit of sample data via `addV` and `addE` steps it always helps people test their answers.